# Hide element on documet.click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a login form. Once logged in, the user name shows on page. If mouserover on the name, the logout link shows. If i click on document logout link need to be hide. I got through ng-mouseover. But if i click on document it not be hide

```
<a class="usrname" ng-mouseover="lgout='false'" ng-init="lgout='true'">Mr. Admin</a>
                        <br />
<a id="A4" class="logout" href="LogIn.aspx" style="float: right;" ng-hide="lgout">Logout</a>
```

My Script

```
$(document).click(function () {
                  var scope = angular.element($("lgout")).scope();
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                  scope.selectValue = 'true';
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line:

```
var scope = angular.element($("lgout")).scope();
```

with this:

```
var scope = angular.element($("#A4")).scope();
```

**NOTE:** It is bad practice to find scope in global method instead do it in controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("test", function ($scope) {
    $scope.lgout = false;

    $(document).click(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.lgout = false;
        });
    });
});
```